# Is Whey protein good for low-carb diet?

Tags: diet, low-carb

Today I tried the EAS AdvantEdge 100% Whey Protein.

Below their website description:

> 23 grams of high quality protein. Only
>   3 grams of carbohydrates. High
>   concentration of BCAAs. Protein is on
>   of the fuels that helps make athletes
>   go. To help support peak performance
>   and optimal muscle growth, the protein
>   you put in you body needs to be high
>   quality. EAS 100 percent Whey Protein
>   is high biological value protein that
>   is naturally abundant in branched
>   chain amino acids ( BCAAs). Research
>   shows that BCAAs- isoleucine, leucine,
>   and valine- support muscle protein
>   synthesis and thus may help muscles
>   recuperate from strenuous exercise.
>   EAS 100 percent Whey Protein is
>   isolated through a series of
>   filtration steps, and instantized for
>   ease of mixability. This produces a
>   great- tasting, high quality protein
>   that mixes easily in to water or your
>   favorite beverage. 100 percent of the
>   protein in this product comes from
>   whey.

I will like to know if drinking this type of shakes will damage a low-carb diet?

Comment: I don't think so, when I go on my diet I have an ISO Whey protein shake and cut down on the carbs and actually helps burning fats.  For me anyway.

Comment: Off topic according to the [FAQ] since the scope change of the site excluded questions not related to exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a low carb diet, 23 grams of protein to 3 grams of carbs is fantastic.

Whether or not a low carb diet is a good idea or if protein shakes deliver results to anyone other than body builders is a different question altogether.

Comment: +1 for answering the question. I think low carb diets are as sound as anything else, and protein shakes are a great way to supplement your protein intake, both for price and convenience.